# Remove notification emblems on Ubuntu Dock 23.04

Tags: gnome, notification, emblem

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 22.10 to Ubuntu 23.04 and it seems nice. The only thing I do not like is the new emblem which counts the notifications. Is it possible to remove it but keep the notifications in the notification area?

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Just open up a terminal and type `gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock show-icons-emblems false`